# Regular expressions wildcard

Tags: regex

It's day 001 for me on regular expressions so sorry if this is a bit stupid, I've done some research but can't find an answer for my question; probably just because I'm searching for the wrong thing.

I have a huge .CVS file and I want to delete all entries containing the term:

```
Subscribe to Newsletter:         No
```

The entries are not uniform - by this I mean

```
--

Anything could be here

Subscribe to Newsletter:         No

--
```

I've thinned this .CSV right down using regular expressions (I think? I'm using Find and Replace in Sublime 3) to delete all the elements I can and I'm almost there. What I'm looking for is a way to use a wildcard to ignore the part I don't know; like this:

```
^.*--

**wild-card**

Subscribe to Newsletter:         No.*\n
```

If anyone can recommend where I can research how to do this that would be fabulous, as I said I might be well off here as it's literally day 1 so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: If you already have the column text for the line, by simply searching `Subscribe to Newsletter:\s*No` should find it.

Comment: As far as learning regex [regex101](https://www.regex101.com) is a great resource. They have a complete guide to the syntax alongside an interface that allows you to test patterns interactively and see exactly how they're working.

Comment: @sln Won't that only delete the Subscribe to Newsletter line? I want to delete the whole entry - if it contains that string then I want to delete the whole entry from the commas to the next, does that make sense?

Comment: @Joshua Kleveter - That's fantastic, that looks really useful! I'll have a play and see how I get on - I think I'll be able to manage this now, I didn't know what 'regex' was :-)

Comment: You'd better show a delimited sample of the _huge CSV_ file, or nobody knows what the context is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st issue: The dot `.` doesn't match newlines unless you use the DOTALL flag - you need that to span multiple lines.

You need a negative look ahead `(?!--)` to assert that dots don't match accross segment delimiters `--`.

Try this:

```
(?s)^--((?!--).)*?Subscribe to Newsletter:\s+No((?!--).)*
```

You dont need the trailing newline, since the dot will match it with the dotall flag `(?s)` enabled.